# Simple deep-learning prediction

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, deep-learning, synaptic.js

I'm starting to learn about deep-learning and found `synaptic.js`.

I would like to create a prediction system where I have a input of numbers and would like the AI to understand the pattern.

My training data would be a array of 2 numbers, and the output I want to validate is [x, y, z] where x and z are kind of booleans for even/odd, and y is the sum of both numbers in the imput.

So:

```
var trainingSet = [{
    'input': [20, 34],
    'output': [1, 54, 0]
}, {
    'input': [22, 33],
    'output': [1, 55, 1]
},{
    'input': [24, 35],
    'output': [1, 59, 1]
},{
    'input': [23, 36],
    'output': [0, 59, 0]
}];
```

and I would like the AI to know the answer if I input `[20, 31]`.

How would I set up such logic?

I started a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbvfgxmp/) based on a [YouTube talk](https://youtu.be/iloeLN6hvrc?t=15m14s) but don't understand what the code does actually...

Made a loop to generate trainig data [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2oxhkbk/) that basically is:

```js
// training data generator:
var trainingSet = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.input = [
        Math.random() * 10,
        Math.random() * 10
    ].map(Math.round);
    obj.output = [
        Number(obj.input[0] % 2 == 0),
        obj.input[0] + obj.input[1],
        Number(obj.input[1] % 2 == 1)
    ]
 trainingSet.push(obj);
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(trainingSet);
```

Comment: Maybe you selected the language and the problem (both bad choices for NNs), but you did not add any own attempt. This looks like bad preparation. **Edit:** After visiting this jsFiddle link (not the best way to go on SO), there is maybe a simple model, but if that's really a (linear) perceptron, it won't work well and you will learn that within the first parts of any good Neural-Network course (is the model-complexity enough for your problem? Is your problem linear-separable? No and No). So learn the theory first.

Comment: @sascha I don't see any reason to downvote this problem. It's specific, well-described and author clearly made an attempt to solve it. Saying "learn theory" is useless and can be applied to majority of questions on SO. To the author: Correct if I am wrong, but shouldn't the problem be rather reversed? In your statement you want to predict the input based on output, so effectively output should be your training.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski _"output should be your training"_ - makes sense. Didn't think of that way to look at the problem. Will try to reverse the logic and use the output as data instead.

Comment: To the solution then! Unless the generator you build is simply to explain the problem to us, there's no way the problem can be solved. More formally, no function exists such that you can recover the input from the output. The generator produces random numbers and what is preserved is whether they were odd / even and the sum. There exists an infinite set of numbers that fulfills these criteria. From your example: 54 = 20 + 34 = 18 + 36 = 16 + 38 ... If there was a process driving this, it can be done. But it's random. Your neural network can never learn a pattern because there is no pattern.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski that is valuable information to organize my way to think and aproach this. _"no function exists such that you can recover the input from the output"_ - this will be my starting point instead. Thank you!. If you want to provide this comment as a answer, please do. Otherwise will be deleting this question soon. Although I think bad thesis should also be published so others leanrn with them :) Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it helped. It's indeed not a bad idea to go through some more "learning resources". I can recommend e.g. neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com or cs231n.github.io (Stanford). The latter dwells into computer vision, but it's great to follow anyway even if you are not into this. Also, for starter I'd recommend going for e.g. Python and some high-level libraries like Keras. Once you get a hang of it, carry on with JS. As for the problem: next time you can try to teach your ANN how to e.g. add numbers or XOR. Something that has a process behind it. Cheers!

Comment: @LukaszTracewski thank you! Will check it out! I saw `synaptic.js` and also`convnet.js`, are there other active/interesting JavaScript/Node projects? I would like to learn neural networks and 1 API. If I start with 5 different APIs I might get lost and have a slow learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the generator you build is simply to explain the problem to us, there's no way the problem can be solved. More formally, no function exists such that you can recover the input from the output. The generator produces random numbers and what is preserved is whether they were odd / even and the sum. There exists an infinite set of numbers that fulfills these criteria. From your example: 54 = 20 + 34 = 18 + 36 = 16 + 38 ... If there was a process driving this, it can be done. But it's random. Your neural network can never learn a pattern because there is no pattern.